# Invariant measure on affine charts of complex Grassmannian

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, grassmannians, homogeneous-spaces, haar-measure

Consider the complex Grassmannian $U(n)/U(k)\times U(n-k)$ with it's $U(n)$-invariant measure. The affine chart corresponding to $i_1, \ldots, i_k$ is given by $n\times k$ matrices for which the submatrix given by columns corresponding to $i_1, \ldots, i_k$ is the $k\times k$ identity matrix $E_k$.

Consider for example the chart given by $1, \ldots, k$ which consists of matrices $(I_k | X),$ where $X$ is arbitrary $k\times (n-k)$ complex matrix. The span of it's rows defines an open subset of $Gr(n, k)$ and the assignment $X \mapsto \mathrm{rowspan}\, (I_k|X)$ is bijective.

What is the formula for the restriction of the invariant measure in terms of entries of $X$?

Answer (score 2):

I don't have the book handy, but I seem to remember that this formula is written out explicitly in S.-s Chern's *Complex manifolds without potential theory (Second Edition)*, in the chapter "The Grassmann manifold".

**Added after finding a copy of the book:**  Yes, as I expected, the formula the OP seeks is developed on pages 78–81 of the above source.  (One may need to read a bit before this to make sure that one understands Chern's notation.)

Comment: Thank you very much!